# Pandas DataFrame to drop rows in the groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with three columns `Date`, `Advertiser` and ID. I grouped the data firsts to see if volumns of some Advertisers are too small (For example when `count()` less than 500). And then I want to drop those rows in the group table.

```
df.groupby(['Date','Advertiser']).ID.count()
```

The result likes this:

```
 Date         Advertiser
 2016-01        A             50000
                B               50
                C              4000
                D             24000
 2016-02        A              6800
                B              7800
                C               123
 2016-03        B              1111
                E              8600
                F               500
```

I want a result to be this:

```
 Date         Advertiser
 2016-01        A             50000
                C              4000
                D             24000
 2016-02        A              6800
                B              7800
 2016-03        B              1111
                E              8600
```

Followed up question:

How about if I want to filter out the rows in groupby in term of the total `count()` in date category. For example, I want to `count()` for a date larger than 15000. The table I want likes this:

```
Date         Advertiser
 2016-01        A             50000
                B               50
                C              4000
                D             24000
 2016-02        A              6800
                B              7800
                C               123
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a Series object after the `groupby`, which can be filtered based on value with a chained *lambda* filter:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Advertiser']).ID.count()[lambda x: x >= 500]

#Date     Advertiser
#2016-01  A             50000
#         C              4000
#         D             24000
#2016-02  A              6800
#         B              7800
#2016-03  B              1111
#         E              8600
#         F               500
```

Comment: This is definitely what I want. Didn't realize can be done so easily. I tried to use **filter(lambda x: x.count()>500)**. It seemed to work. However it is not. Could you also explain why filter function is not working well? Thanks!

Comment: I believe `groupby.filter` should also work if you want to keep the result as a data frame, for instance, `df.groupby(['Date', 'Advertiser']).filter(lambda g: g.ID.size >= 500)` or `df.groupby(['Date', 'Advertiser']).filter(lambda g: g.ID.count() >= 500)`. In your case, `x` is a data frame, `x.count()` returns a series but you need a scalar value here in order to filter groups.

Comment: Where is the question? Maybe give a link?

Comment: You can try this `df.groupby(['Date','Advertiser']).ID.count().groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: x.sum() > 15000)` group by the 0 level of the index which is the date, and then filter based on the sum of count.

Comment: hmm, this is not working well, even though there isn't error coming up. I think your logic is very clear. I thought it should work.

Comment: Maybe this is not the issue, but Your second group has a sum of count smaller than 15000, so if you set your threshold to be 15000, it won't show up.

Comment: Yea, I think your logic is correct. How about if I group by more than 2 level at the beginning. In the second groupby of your syntax above, if I want to aggregate in term of level=0 and level=1. Should **groupby(level=0,level=1) **work?

Comment: You can use `groupby(level=[0,1])`.